# How to add event handler to first item in Vue loop?

Tags: loops, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a list of items I am iterating through and need to programmatically add an event handler to the first rendered element. I do not see how this is possible in Vue.

```
<div ref="componentList" class="component-list col-9">
            <template
                v-for="( course, index ) in sortedCourseList"
            >
                <span
                    v-if="( index > 0 ) && (course.courseTitle[ 0 ] !== sortedCourseList[ index - 1].courseTitle[ 0 ])"
                    :id="course.courseTitle[ 0 ]"
                    :key="index"
                    class="component-list__letter-heading"
                >
                    {{ course.courseTitle[ 0 ] }}
                </span>
                <CardLong
                    v-else
                    :key="index"
                    :ref="'card' + index"
                    >>> EVENT HANDLER <<<
                    :title="{
                        text: course.courseTitle,
                        order: 1,
                    }"
                    titleTag="h2"
                    icon
                />
            </template>
        </div>
```

I am looking where to implement something like

```
if ( index === 0 ) { ... }
```

in the CardLong component instance.

Comment: what is this "event handler" you are talking about?

Comment: In theory, it could be anything, such as ```@click``` Specifically, I am using a library called vue-intersect and will be utilizing the ```@enter``` event handler which creates an IntersectionObserver listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ternary operator to conditionally call a function on your event, whatever that is:

```
<div v-for="(a, i) in [1,2,3,4]" :key="i" @click="i == 0 ? doSomething() : ''">
  Click Me!
</div>
```